# SVG dx+text-anchor middle have different behavior into chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg, d3.js

I would like to write a code not browser dependent. My goal is to display an arc with a centered text inside:

[image]

To do so I use d3.js to draw an arc:

```
var elem = vis.append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", myarc(inR, outR, startA, endA, orient))
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")
    .attr("fill", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.2)
    .style("stroke", "#BBB")
    .attr("id", "0_1");
```

Then I bind the text to it to make it follow the arc and then shift it from half the radius of the arc in the `y` direction and half the angle length in the `x` direction:

```
text.append("text")
    .style("font-size", "14px")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("dx", spaceLength / 2.0)
    .attr("dy", 25)
    .attr("method", "stretch")
    .attr("spacing", "auto")
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#0_1")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Test text :)");
```

My problem is that Chrome and Firefox do not render this code the same way. The `dx` attribute is shifting two times more the text to the right in Chrome than in Firefox.

Here is how it renders with Firefox:

[image]

To make it work in Firefox I have to replace:

```
    .attr("dx", spaceLength / 2.0)
```

by

```
    .attr("dx", spaceLength)
```

How to make this code display the same on both browsers without implementing a browser detection function?

What is creating this difference of rendering in the two browsers?

The full code sample reproducing the issue is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/taxQK/1/

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you should be able to use `.attr("startOffset", "50%")` instead of `dx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text support was rewritten in Firefox 25 which has just been released and your example works as you expect when I try in that version. It may be that all you need to do is update to the latest released version of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This library has implementations of rotating text on the outside of a circle that works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE. Though I do not recommend using it, its source code should reveal the trick.

https://github.com/danielstern/MagicCircles

Disclosure: this is my library.